# Sustainable suit fabric

Tags: fabric

I'm in the need for a new suit - several actually, I'm getting married.

I want the suit to be made sustainably, but living in Singapore there are no tailors that I can find that use sustainable fabric.

I have found a tailor who's happy to use fabric that I find.

How can I find a sustainable fabric manufacturer that would be prepared to sell fabric in small enough quantity for only 5 suits?

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you mentioned what type of fabric you are planning to use since there are several types of fabric. In the U.S., wool is pretty common and can be purchased through small websites. Since you are in Asia, perhaps you can look into cashmere or silk and look for "organic" producers, probably very difficult since certification is not as organized there.

I am guessing polyester would be too cheap for a wedding and whether that is sustainable depends on how you view the plastics industry.

Comment: Silk or wool are both good - they do still use wool for suits here in the tropics.
Yes, no polyester please :-)